# Natural Response of Parallel RLC Circuit

Tags: passive-networks

In the circuit shown below, I need to calculate the current through the capacitor, which is initially charged. I'm thinking I have to calculate the natural response of the circuit, but am unsure of how to do so. I can calculate the impedance and find the pole, but then what?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUNpIy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Use KCL. get 2nd order linear differential equations...Solve it.......just see the standard example from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Theory/RLC_Circuits

Answer (score 1):

Let's write down equations in laplace form :

Z total = R || LS || 1/CS

Z total = R / [1+R(CS+1/LS)]

It is total impedance of circuit. If we assume initial conditions Vc0- = V0, and IL0- = I0, then for Ic we can write this equation:

Ic = Vc / Zc

Ic = [I0 * Ztotal + V0] / (1/CS)

Ic = I0 * R / [ 1/CS + R(1+1/LCS^2)] + V0 * CS

This is current equation of Capacitor in laplace form.

Answer (score 0):

Write down all the equations, then convert them all to common a unit.  (I think I always end up working in Coulombs.)  Solve that and then find the current.  (Hint, it's a damped oscillator)

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say that it's an oscillator.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri, Ah OK, for a large range of R values it will oscillate.  (I call that an oscillator... for me it doesn't have to go on forever.)  I'll agree to disagree.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold In the interests of harmony, perhaps we could agree to call it a (damped) "Harmonic Oscillator"? ;-)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, fixed.